# how to add mail boxes to iis 7 smtp

Tags: iis-7, smtp, mailbox

may be an easy one for the pros but for me quite hard..

Hi

I have installed iis7 and enabled SMTP. Where do i start adding email addresses.

I know this sounds stupid but I just dont know where to start out.

Thanks,
Kieran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SMTP server installed with IIS is not a full fledged e-mail server. It is used to send/route email, but does not have e-mail boxes.

Windows 2008 does not include the the POP3 services that would be required for what you want to do. (It was included in Windows 2003, but removed again in 2008)

Microsoft obviously wants you to purchase Exchange licensing, but if you google for something like windows mail server you will be able to find some free alternatives that should fit your needs.